# Cassandra: when to add a new node

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

It looks like there are multiple criteria for deciding when it's time to add a new node to a ring / cluster, the most easy one being the disk getting close to half full, but there are others too like insufficient memory/heap, frequent and long GCs. So what is the comprehensive list of criteria one should monitor and the trigger points for those that determine it's time to add a new node to a ring in the cluster?

What is supposed to happen as we close to the limits - will the client request response times slow down or cassandra starts crashing and nodes go down.  I have seen the latter in my case, hence the question.

FWIW, I'm using datastax community edition of cassandra, version 2.1.1.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You know you need to add nodes to your cluster if you:

1) You have reached the maximum data density that your node can withstand. Can be around 1-3 TB with SSD's.

2) Your cluster cannot keep up with your workload as far as transactions per second go.

Issues like long GC pauses might be side effects of these two drivers, but they can also often be addressed through JVM tuning. This also applies to OOM's, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you provide more specific info in your answer? When do we know we have crossed the threshold for the data density - is it when GCs > 1s start? And what is the standard for acceptable transactions per second?

Comment: If you experience GC thrashing, first try tuning -- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8150

Tps is very dependent on your hardware.

Comment: Another hint is if you're seeing dropped mutations or if you're not hitting your performance SLA's.